# Javascript to delete cookie on android web browser

Tags: javascript, android, cookies

What is the javascript to delete a cookie on android web browser. The usual method of setting an expiration date of the cookie to a date in the past does not work in android web browser.

For e.g. the below code works in desktop web browsers and mobile safari but does not work in android web browser.

```
document.cookie = 'cookiename=cookievalue; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
```

Comment: That's really weird. I was expecting that it works on Android browser as well.

Comment: yes it is really weird. I had to end up expiring the cookie on the server side and adding the expired cookie back to the response.

Comment: @AlwaysSmile Which browsers you are talking about? Does it work on chrome or firefox for android?

Comment: May be [this](http://www.shaydesdsgn.com/post/43877423403/android-webview-with-cookies) can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen browsers (actually in TV sets, but not sure which it was exactly), that did not accept the 'expires=' field (with an absolute date), but worked well with 'max-age=' (live-time in number of seconds from now). So maybe try to delete the cookie by:

```
document.cookie = 'cookiename=; max-age=0; path=/';
```

Comment: I using an old Android system (5.0.2) and after I replaced with it's code it became working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried also including the domain in the cookie setting line? I remember that in some cases you had to be very explicit with the domain and path matching (or being compatible with) the current document location in order to delete a cookie:

```
document.cookie='cookiename=cookievalue; path=/; domain=current-domain; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT';
```

Answer (score 1):

that works for me

```
document.cookie = yourCookieName + '=' + // NO value here 
    ';expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';
```

if used path and/or domain at set time, add em

```
document.cookie = yourCookieName + '=' + // NO value here
    ';path=' + yourCookiePath +
    ';domain=' + yourCookieDomain +
    ';expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';
```

Answer (score -1):

While this is a roundabout way of doing so, create and instantiate a JavascriptInterface that will be called from the webpage Javascript. Set that Javascript interface to your Webview using

```
webSettings.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

and

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterfaceImplementation(), INTERFACE_NAME);
```

On your web page you then invoke

```
javascript:INTERFACE_NAME.yourSessionClearingMethod();
```

which should contain

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();        
cookieManager.removeAllCookie(); // or cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
```

to clear said unwanted cookie(s).

Comment: This is not an iOS question, it's an in-browser Safari, JavaScript question. Nothing related to webviews.

Comment: FlorianMargaine: replace iOS with Android and Safari with Chrome (or AOSP Browser)